# collection_select without using symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question which should not be so difficult but I didn't find something similar and I'm not a rails expert. I want to change the names into the database trough a collection_select without adding new data.
I have these two models:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :patient
 has_many :structures,dependent: :destroy
end
########
class Structure < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :plan
end
```

I upload some files which save data in plan and structures e.g  plan name,..
I now need a form for @plan to fill in the kind of diagnose and I want also to change the names of the structure with some default name I decided (since structure names from uploaded files are different between file to file but have the same meaning )

```
  <%= form_for @plan do |f| %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "plans_DefaultstructureNames.js" %>

<p><strong>Please select the diagnose:</strong><br>
 <%= f.collection_select :diagnose, ['SRS', 'SRT', 'SBRTLung', 'SBRTLiver', 'SBRTPancreas', 'SBRTProstate'], :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true,prompt: true%>
 </p>
<div id="SrsSrtDefault">
  <p>
  <strong>BODY</strong>
     <%= f.collection_select :plan,:structure,@plan.structure.name , :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true,prompt: true%>
   </p>
    <p>
<strong>PTV1</strong>
  <%= f.collection_select :plan,:structure,@plan.structure.name , :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true,prompt: true%>
</p>
 </div>
```

Imagine that @plan.structure.name contains BOD and PTV1. I want that the user changes BOD to BODY trough a collection select but I really don't have clou..
Hope it's clear..Cheers

Comment: @aashish the plan.structure.name contains several names e.g {bod,suggestion,..}. I want to force user to save these names in a standard form e.g {body,advice,..} (which are synonym of bod and suggestions). Therefore I want a drop down menu where it's asked: "to what correspond bod?" the user has to select "body" and after the submission in plan.structures.name we will have "body" and not "bod" anymore.

Comment: probably I should use some javascript in order to be able to save the same variable name in different models.. what do you think?

Comment: can you explain in detailed steps.